# Python 'add' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to find the intersection between a ray and a 3D surface, given in spherical coordinates r=f(theta).

Not sure how to do simply in Python, I first converted the surface equation into Cartesian.
And I used sympy module, to solve the 2nd order parametric equation about t.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

def mpn(Pd,Bz,X,Y,Z,px,py,pz):

    r0=(10.22+1.29*np.tanh(0.184*(Bz+8.14)))*Pd**(-1/6.6)
    alpha=(0.58-0.007*Bz)*(1+0.024*np.log(Pd))

    t=Symbol('t',positive="True")
    x=X+px*t
    y=Y+py*t
    z=Z+pz*t

    sol=solve(x**2+y**2+z**2-r0**2*(2/(1+x/np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)))**(2*alpha),t)[0]
    return (X+px*sol,Y+py*sol,Z+pz*sol)

sol=mpn(3.69,-4.20,-6.71,-10.3,-5.05,0.0582,0.0012,-0.9983)
```

But this makes weird error, 'Add' object has no attribute 'sqrt'.
I don't know why this is happening cuz I used np.sqrt, not Add.sqrt or +.sqrt or something. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sympy.sqrt() instead of numpy.sqrt().

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a reason for that?

Comment: I may be wrong but in my understanding numpy.sqrt() will only work in numerical expressions. For symbolic ones you need the sympy function.